# PyCharm procedural __all__ generation and syntax highlighting

Tags: python, pycharm, static-analysis

I'm using this decorator to manage `__all__` in a DRY manner:

```
def export(obj):
    mod = sys.modules[obj.__module__]
    if hasattr(mod, '__all__'):
        mod.__all__.append(obj.__name__)
    else:
        mod.__all__ = [obj.__name__]

    return obj
```

For names imported with `import *` PyCharm issues an `unresolved reference` error, which is understandable, since it doesn't run the code before analysis. But it is an obvious inconvenience.

How would you solve it (or maybe already solved)?

*My assumptions*:

- Adding some automatic linter plugin or altering existing PyCharm's inspection code would be fine.
- Something that's actually editing a `.py` source is viable, but not fine.
- This method is probably not the best one, therefore suggesting another convenient technique of dealing with exports is fine too.

Comment: pyi stubs could be used, see [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and [PEP-561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/)

Comment: @user2235698 That's a nice one! Could you advise some method to update this stub automatically and provide a simple example of the py, pyi files and their usage (to see how your idea should work)? I would tick that answer.

Comment: I have not seen well enough tool to automatically update stubs, you could start with [stubgen](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/stubgen.py) and manually update stubs to make them more precise. [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) and [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/master/src/attr/__init__.pyi) could be a good example, most linters support such stubs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in an alternative approach to managing `__all__`:

https://pypi.org/project/auto-all/

This provides a `start_all()` and `end_all()` function to place in your module around the items you want to make accessible.  This approach works with PyCharms code inspection.

```
from auto_all import start_all, end_all

# Imports outside the start and end function calls are not included in __all__.
from pathlib import Path

def a_private_function():
    print("This is a private function.")

# Start defining externally accessible objects.
start_all(globals())

def a_public_function():
    print("This is a public function.")

# Stop defining externally accessible objects.
end_all(globals())
```

I feel like this is a reasonable approach to managing `__all__`, and one that I used on more complex packages.  The source code for the package is small, so could easily be included direct in your code to avoid external dependencies if you need.

The reason I use this is I have some modules where lots of items need to be "exported" and a I want to keep imported items out of the export list.  I have multiple developers working on the code and it's easy to add new items and forget to include them in `__all__`, so automating this helps.

Comment: Well, still not quite linter-friendly, but I suppose the project will eventually come to that. For now it is the closest to being a perfect solution, thanks for sharing!